# Read an input from the terminal

Tags: c

I'm doing a project and I have to read data from the terminal.

So the program is started normally and the user has to give some instructions.
I would like the program to wait for the instructions given by the user (taping in the terminal) and then execute all of them.

I can only use the function `read` to get the input.
Until now, I found the way bellow

```
int main (void)
{
    char line[50];
    int ret;

    printf ("\nEnter string below\n");
    while ((ret = read(0, line, 50)) != -1)
    {
        line[ret] = '\0';
        printf ("result %s\n", line);
    }
}
```

It works but I would like to type all the instructions and then when pressing ENTER quit the input mode and treat them.

Is it possible ?
Also, is there a common way to quit the imput mode using CRTL + D

Thanks

Comment: `imput`? :D good.

Comment: You are not using `read` function, you are using `getline` function. Verify this with your instructor or whatever.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's unclear how you want to manage the input information or what they represent, but if you want to manage them as individual strings, you could use an array of strings (or equivalently, an array of character pointers that point to dynamically allocated string buffers).

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use `read` as a variable name as it's a function in the standard libraries

Comment: Input is line oriented. User composes a line in the terminal, then presses enter. You receive it, then prompt for the next line. If you don't prompt then user is confused and lost, but you don't have to prompt. You must read line by line however.

Comment: I update the code.
So I can only read line by line. It seams to be ok, but how the user can quit the input mode when he has finishes to give instructions ?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: `read` is not part of the C standard library, but part of POSIX (and possbly other systems).

Comment: @Olaf - You're correct about my misspeaking, but in 99.99999% of the cases, that doesn't matter ;) And, this is not one of the cases where it matters, specifically because the OP has been tasked with using `read` as a function - which is going to cause problems if he has a variable named `read`.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Actually **most** systems C is used for do **not** support `read`. But those also will not provide `getline` or the standard library except for headers mandatory for a freestanding implementation. For a hosted environment, the name is a legacy and violates actually the rules for reserved names: a user can assume a name without leading underscore to be available for his application, unless he explicitly includes a header for it or has to define a macro for conditional declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do

```
while (read(0, line, 50) > 0)
    printf("%s\n", line);
```

But if you do so, you'll have troubles if you have the first input with 42 characters for example and the second input with 30 because the read function does not reset the "line" buffer.
Use memset if you can or make your own function to do it !

Why > 0 and not != -1 : Because read returns -1 if it's an error and 0 if it's the end of the input.